# Batch scripting and regex

Tags: batch-file

I need to cat .png files into several pdf, all the .png files are in the same folder with the same name ending with a sequence of number (such as Filename000.png to Filename099.png).

For instance I need do:

```
$ convert Filename000.png Filename001.png Filename002.png Mypdf1.pdf
$ convert Filename003.png Mypdf2.pdf
$ convert Filename004.png Filename005.png Mypdf3.pdf
```

I have a list with the end of the files name I need to cat together. For instance (according to the example above):

```
000..002 
0003
004..005
```

I want to automatize the task with a batch script, is it possible to call the list to indicate the end of the files name that I want to cat together ? 
Maybe I first need to insert a regular expression into a command line ? I know that with echo I can generate the list of caracter I want, like `$ echo {000..002}`. But I don't know how to write that line.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site for programmers, but it is not a free code/script writing service. So you have to try it on your own and, when stuck, come back with a specific question and providing a [mcve] by [edit]ing your post. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Type `FOR /?` for help on the syntax and use `FOR /L` to loop through successive values, and `FOR /F` to read lines from a file (such as a file containing the above list of numbers). Give it a try and if you get errors, post your code by editing your question (click "edit" above).

Comment: Your code examples show a `$` as your console prompt.  This tells me you are not using cmd.exe as your shell.  What operating system and shell are you using?\

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky, as I found the task interresting,
despite the fact you didn't provide any own code.

Provided there is a file `combine.txt` with this content:

```
> type Combine.txt
000..002
003
004..005
```

I number the lines in the batch with findstr to get the output pdf name:

```
> findstr /N "^" Combine.txt
1:000..002
2:003
3:004..005
```

This batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\13\SO_50841203.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "List=Combine.txt"
Set "Prefix=Filename"
Set "Ext=.png"

:: number list entries with findstr and process
For /f "tokens=1,2* delims=.:" %%A in (
  'Findstr /n "^" ^<"%List%" '
) Do (
  set "Range="
  Set "PDF=Mypdf%%A.pdf"
  if "%%C" neq "" (
    REM use a for /l to iterate the range (with a 1 in front for leading zeroes
    for /L %%D in (1%%B,1,1%%C) Do (
      Set "Num=%%D"
      Set "Range=!Range! %Prefix%!NUM:~-3!%Ext%"
    )
  ) else (
    Set "NUM=%%B"
    Set "Range= %Prefix%!NUM:~-3!%Ext%"
  )
  Echo convert !Range:~1! !PDF!
)
```

produces this output (only echoed for testing)

```
> Q:\Test\2018\06\13\SO_50841203.cmd
convert Filename000.png Filename001.png Filename002.png Mypdf1.pdf
convert Filename003.png Mypdf2.pdf
convert Filename004.png Filename005.png Mypdf3.pdf
```